# Unable to Use Managed flow in the different Org

Tags: recordtriggeredflow

I have created a record-triggered flow to update the status fields depending on the date field updated, I made it a Managed flow to use on the different org(this has a namespace) so when it is activated it throws an error which is not giving the actual error
please give any suggestions

Comment: Please provide the error that is reported. Did you put it in an unlocked or managed 2GP? If you look at the metadata, does the flow refer to other metadata also in the package? Do all references include the relevant namespace prefix? Always [edit] your question to add more detail and include exact error details.

Comment: I have received the email as follows
If you install a non-template flow from a managed package, error emails for that flow’s interviews don’t include any details about the individual flow elements. The email is sent to either the user who installed the flow or the Apex exception email recipients.
Flow API Name: SymphonyLF__StatusUpdate
Type: Autolaunched Flow
Version: 3
Status: Active
FlowInterviewDetails
InterviewLabel: Status 11.01.2024, 01:25
Interview GUID: 66680e99f518fd98f63e75d3c79018cf719122-bdaf
Start time: 11.01.2024, 01:25
Salesforce Error ID: 1139328461-11631 (1840415794)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the detail, and use markdown formatting to make the email content stand out. It looks like you are getting a gack code. You could raise a salesforce support case to find out more about it.